# How to detect if a number between a coma (.) is >= 0 and <= 255?

Tags: c++, detection, ipv4

it's for detecting ipv4 adressess
for instance:
255.255.1.0 = true
277.255.1.0 = false
because 277 is higher than 255
how do i detect this on every number seperated by comas? Anyone got an idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use the less-than operator for example.

Comment: You could use a regex.

Comment: I tried nothing because i dont know what would i do if someone typed 001 how do i convert that to integer of value 1. The whole address is 1 string btw.

Comment: Rather than parsing the numbers manually, why not use an existing function that is specifically designed to parse IP addresses? Like `inet_addr()`, `inet_pton()`, `getaddrinfo()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string into four numbers via the `sscanf` function from the `<cstdio>` header as follows:

```
    std::string test = "1.1.1.1";
    int numbers[4];
    //Check if returned value is 4 if you aren't sure the input is in the right format
    sscanf( test.c_str(), "%i.%i.%i.%i", &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2], &numbers[3] );
```

After that you can iterate the array to check for invalid numbers or use `<algorithm>`:

```
    bool valid = std::none_of( a, a + 4, []( int i ){ return ( i < 0 ) || ( i > 255 ); });
```

However if you are writing something networking-related I would just check the return-value of `inet_pton`, since you will probably make that function call anyway and it return 1 on success and 0 if the supplied string is not a valid address.

Comment: `!std::any_of` is what `std::none_of` does.